# Pass arguments to parent Dockerfile

Tags: docker, arguments, dockerfile

Is there any way to use the arguments defined in the parent docker image?

Given the following child Dockerfile

```
FROM jenkins

USER ${user}

RUN echo "${user}"
```

Excerpt from parent [Dockerfile](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/blob/master/Dockerfile)

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk

ARG user=jenkins
ARG group=jenkins
ARG uid=1000
ARG gid=1000
```

Answer (score 16):

[Build arguments](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/arg) are not persisted in images, so they will not be available in builds `FROM` a parent image.

> Unlike an ARG instruction, ENV values are always persisted in the built image.
>
> ARG variables are not persisted into the built image as ENV variables are.

The arguments can be persisted by storing them somewhere, the easiest place is in an environment variable.

```
ARG IMAGE_USER=jenkins
ENV IMAGE_USER=$IMAGE_USER
```

All `RUN` steps in the child image will then have access to `IMAGE_USER` in their environment.

Comment: Could I somehow extract the current value of the USER directive in my `Dockerfile` and save it before I override the USER. Something like this:
`user=${USER}`, then `USER root`, then do stuff, then `USER ${user}`?

Comment: @lanoxx No, not with Dockers build system. You could store the user somewhere in the image file system and use something like [`gosu`](https://github.com/tianon/gosu) in shell to get back to that stored user.